# Translation needed for 4 Chinese characters

Tags: translation

[image: characters]

I know that separately they should mean something like "beauty", "love", "friend", "mad", but written like this, do they form a sentence?

Comment: source? internet search seems to confirm that this is an uncommon combination, even 友狂 seems to be uncommon, 从何而来？正如互联网搜索会证实那样，这很可能算是一个罕见组合字，甚至"友狂"太罕见

Comment: cf.宗教狂、政治狂,religious/political fanatic,工作狂workaholic、偷窥狂voyeur  美爱友 iciba 翻译 the beauty of love, therefore perhaps "beauty of love fanatic"

Comment: I bet 50 cents: these random characters come from a tattoo.

Comment: I second the tattoo bet. On a white dude with long hair and a permanent, hazy, mile stare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's slightly analyze them:

According to: http://xh.5156edu.com/

The following characters falls in these parts of speech:

```
美:【形】 【動】 【量】
愛:【動】 【名】
友:【動】 【名】
狂:【形】 【動】
```

Since these characters would definitely **not** make a valid sentence in Modern Chinese, let's assume we are dealing with Classical Chinese.

A typical Classical Chinese sentence consist of: `主語、謂語、賓語` or you can understand it like `Subject Predicate Object` in English.

This is a possible combination:

【形】【名】【動】【形】

We can do a 詞性活用 (a hack if you will), and make 狂 become a 【名】 to mean "a crazy person". The sentence would mean:

```
Beautiful love befriends with a crazy person.
```

**Please note that this is just for the sake of answering the question.** Don't use it because nobody will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think these four characters form a sentence or phrase.
My guess is this comes from someone's tattoo because these four characters are very common in U.S. But I have never seen them appearing together...

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't form a sentence = = They are just four random words